# Inherit from controller and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

**> Basically : I need go to Login View if not have a session.**

MVC - Inherit from controller and redirect if something do , i need when visit any url go to baseController and do redirect to login if not have session

my problem is : after checked from baseController go to view method and do return view , i need go to login view if not have session

**BaseController :**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        private HttpContextBase Context { get; set; }
        protected BaseController()
        {
            IsLogin();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public RedirectResult IsLogin()
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null &&
                Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString()) > 0)
            {
                //return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
                return Redirect("/Admin/Users/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect("/Admin/Default/Login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller inherit from baseController :

```
public class UnitsController : BaseController 
    {
        protected BaseController baseInit;
        private SuperLinkContext db = new SuperLinkContext();
        // is inaccessible due to its protiction level
        // GET: Admin/Units
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var units = db.Units.Include(u => u.User);
            return View(units.ToList());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Solution for Your Issue.

I have Implement code on OnActionExecuting Method and used RedirectToRouteResult
for redirecting user to Specific controller as you want.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Index",
                controller = "Users",
                area = "Admin"
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Login",
                controller = "Default",
                area = "Admin"
            }));
        }

       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check this, but your solution has a few "design-flaws".
If you decorate a method with `[Authorize]`, that implies, that he is already logged-in. So there is no need to check for a userId in  Session object.

On the other hand, if you `[AllowAnonymous]`, checking the Session object, does not imply, that the user is authenticated. You have to take care of your Session state manually, and if you by any chance forget to remove a session variable after logout or login, you application might misbehave. I tend to store every bit of userinformation I need as claims in the User object.  This way, asp.net takes care of all the plumbing and in the most basic scenario can just check if the request is authorized or not. If I need more fine grained tuning, I can apply policies, to check for different claims.

If you need to check an identifying property, read the users claims:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```

If you need to redirect the user to your Login form, if he is not logged in, you can configure this in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/Default/Login" timeout="3600" />
</authentication>
```

Now everytime a user tries to access a protected resource, he is automatically redirected to your login form, globally.